# How can i set a limit question for my code

Tags: java, android

how do i set a limit question for it

```
 public void setQuestion() {
        Random rand = new Random();
    int value1 = rand.nextInt(100-10) + 10;
    int value2 = rand.nextInt(20-2) + 2;

        int randomquestion = rand.nextInt(4);
        if (randomquestion == 1) {
            question.setText("What is " + value1 + "+" + value2 + " ? ");
            expected = "" + (value1 + value2);
        } else if (randomquestion == 2) {
            question.setText("What is " + value1 + "-" + value2 + " ? ");
            expected = "" + (value1 - value2);
        } else if (randomquestion == 3) {
            question.setText("What is " + value1 + "x" + value2 + " ? ");
            expected = "" + (value1 * value2);
        } else {
            question.setText("What is " + value1 + "÷" + value2 + "?");
            expected = "" + (value1 / value2);
        }

    }
```

i expect it can only come out with 10 question and it will end the activity

Comment: count the questions in the variable

Comment: what did you mean by it Sir

Comment: sorry i didnt understand because im still new in android java

Comment: make a variable which you will increase each time you need by 1, and then check the variable value wherever you need.

Comment: Please state you task more clearly. Do you need to execute 10 different questions or to break the execution if `randomQuestion` is more than 10? Or limit the random number generated into `randomQuestion` to not more than 10?